# VB Listbox item information output to secondary form - all labels

Tags: vb.net, forms, listbox

I am currently working on a project that is giving me some issues. I am using a `listbox` that has predetermined information in its index items. When I select a item, a second form appears that gives the information about that line. Example:

```
List Box Selected items = Bob ----->  Second form all Labels - Bob, work ID number, Job title and phone number.
```

the information can not be changed and is part of an array. I have the array set up and everything is ready to go except I can not figure out how to get the information to the second form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: do you have only one listbox in the form. And second form is also visible in that time

Comment: It is only one listbox and the second form is not displayed until the selected item is chosen. It will then use an array to fill the information on the second form

Comment: See my answer. I think do you want this or tell me i will ready to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim xFrm As New Form2
    xFrm.Label1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    xFrm.Show()

End Sub
```